# Lower-order term constraints and wrong guess

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

I'm a self-taught and I'm studying from CLRS.
I'm having difficulty with this recurrence relation:
$$T(n)=3T\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right) + n$$

The problem is that I can "prove" that $T(n) = \mathcal{O}(n)$. It's absurd.
My inductive hypothesis about $\mathcal{O}(n)$ is:
$$\exists c \gt 0 \,\,\exists n_0 \gt 0 \,\,\exists b \ge 0 \quad\forall n_0\le k\lt n \quad T(k) \le ck - bn \le ck $$

From here I haven't problem during the "proof":
$$\begin{align}
T(n) &\le 3\left(c\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor - bn\right) + n
\\ &\le 3\left(c\frac{n}{2} - bn\right) + n
\\ &= \frac{3}{2}cn - 3bn + n
\\ &= \frac{3}{2}cn -n(3b - 1) \qquad\qquad (1st)
\\ &\le cn
\end{align}$$

The latter holds $\forall b \ge \frac{c+2}{6}$ and it comes from:
$$\frac{3}{2}cn - n(3b - 1) \le cn$$

**--EDIT--**
It's also easy to prove that
$$(1st) \le cn - bn$$
It holds $\forall b \ge \frac{c+2}{4}$
So $$T(n) \le cn - bn$$
**--END EDIT--**

So I think that the hypotheses are wrong. Probably I misunderstanding subtraction of lower-order term. What are the constraints to apply this technique? Only that $T(k) \gt 0$? In this recurrence the latter seems valid.

**Synthesis**: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/65549/lower-order-term-constraints-and-wrong-guess/65579?noredirect=1#comment139380_65579

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: I suggest you try very clearly writing out your base case and inductive hypothesis, including what things are existentially quantified and what are universally quantified. your proof attempt seems to consist mostly of a sequence of statements with no explicit connection between them.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you for your reply. I appreciate it. I edited it in proper way. However in these case the base case is necessary? T(b), where T(b) represents base case, is costant. So you can always find a good costant for asymptotic inequality. So the proof of inductive step is sufficient. Furthermore the base case it's not indicated on the book.

Comment: I do not understand your inductive hypothesis for proving $O(n)$. What is $b$?

Comment: @aelguindy Thank you for your reply. It's a constant that I added to subtract lower-order term, I find this way very flexible.

Comment: @DrunerJohn we know that $T(n)$ is not in $O(n)$, so may I ask you to edit your question in the following way: (1) delete the recursion-tree-based computation, it is not relevant, (2) delete your $\Omega(n)$ proof details, we already know that the function is $\Omega(n)$ (3) write your faulty induction proof that $T(n) \in O(n)$ in sufficient detail. This way we will be able to point out the mistakes in the proof you present. More concretely, write your base case, your induction hypothesis (which you already have) and how you use the hypothesis to prove the statement.

Comment: @aelguindy Ok, I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the way you state the induction hypothesis is a bit strange, and it definitely doesn't prove that $T(n) = O(n)$. Assuming that the induction is on $n$, what your induction hypothesis states (more or less) is that for every $n$ there exists $C$ such that $T(k) \leq Ck$ for all $k \leq n$. The function $T(n) = n^2$ satisfies this, with $C = n$.

What you really want to do is to fix the parameters $b,c,n_0$ in advance. In other words, you want to prove
$$
 \exists b,c,n_0 \, \forall n \, \forall n_0 \leq k \leq n\colon T(k) \leq ck - bn.
$$
You first instantiate $b,c,n_0$, and then you prove only the following part by induction:
$$
\forall n \, \forall n_0 \leq k \leq n\colon T(k) \leq ck - bn.
$$
At each step of the induction, you are proving
$$
\forall n_0 \leq k \leq n\colon T(k) \leq ck - bn
$$
for the current value of $n$.

Now for your mistake. Your induction hypothesis states that for all $k \leq n$,
$$ T(k) \leq ck - bn. $$
However, in the inductive step, you only prove
$$ T(k) \leq ck. $$
Also, you only prove it for $k = n$, despite the form of your actual induction hypothesis.

Indeed, it is very strange that your inductive hypothesis gives an upper bound on $T(k)$ *which depends on $n$*. This is quite unorthodox. Usually the upper bound only depends on $k$. Moreover, you are not really subtracting a *lower-order* term: $n \neq o(k)$!

Here is what an application of subtracting a lower-order term usually looks like. Suppose that we want to prove that $T(n) = O(n)$. Then you find $b,c,n_0$ and prove the following by induction:

$$ \forall n \geq n_0\colon T(n) \leq bn - c\log n.$$

Note that there is no $k$ here, and that $\log n = o(n)$ is indeed of lower order.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. First: do I have to find the three constants? Second: as I suspected my hypothesis is buggy. I didn't want to say that for every n there exist a constant C, but there exists a constant C for all n etc.. Then I stated $T(k) \le ck - bn \le ck$. So if I prove $T(n) \le cn$ why is not valid? However there isn't difficulty to "prove" that $T(n) \le ck - bn$. I've difficulty..

Comment: You need to prove that the constants exist. They don't have to be explicit.

Comment: Your main error is that you assume one thing and prove another. You assume $T(k) \le ck - bn$ but prove $T(k) \le ck$. Induction requires you to assume and prove the *same* property.

Comment: Do you mean by induction? As I say it's easy to "prove" that $T(n) \le cn - bn$.

Comment: I think that my primary problem is that I can't identify hypothesis and thesis. In this case my thesis to $T(n)=O(n)$ is $\forall n \ge n_0 : T(n) \le cn$ isn't that true? I've to prove the latter by induction with this hypothesis: $\exists c,n_0 \forall n_0 \le k \lt n :T(k) \le ck$, isn't that true?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your terminology. You tried to prove some property P by induction, but assumed a stronger property Q as your induction hypothesis. The basic idea, known as *strengthening the induction hypothesis*, works with this modification: you prove property Q by induction. That's not what you do.

Comment: Thesis is what we want to prove. Ok I understand this idea. But sincerely I don't understand where is my mistake... Is it in the proof, is it on the hypothesis or both? You said: *Now for your mistake. Your induction hypothesis states that for all (...) However, in the inductive step, you only prove (...)*. But in the **--EDIT--** section we can reach the correct result.

Comment: Now you have another mistake: you are assuming an upper bound on $T(k)$ for $k\le n$ (specifically, for $k=n/2$) that depends on $n$, but you only prove it for $k=n$. So once again you are not proving the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Maybe the light is near.  Are you talking about this hypothesis : $\exists b,c,n_0 \, \forall n \, \forall n_0 \leq k \leq n\colon T(k) \leq ck - bn$? If I understand my hypothesis is only valid to prove for $k = n$, where n has a prefixed value and k depends on the latter, isn't that true?  So is it valid only for that value of n? I think that we agree that my troubles are caused from my hypothesis. Can you formally state the inductive hypothesis and what we want to prove? Sorry to trouble you, but unfortunately I did more "proofs" with this method, so I want to understand...

Comment: It is *you* who has to decide on an inductive hypothesis. Then you need to apply induction: assuming the inductive hypothesis for $n$, show why it follows for $n+1$ (and don't forget a base case!).

Comment: I went out and I understand where is my mistake.... (Finally) First of all it's the worst hypothesis of the world.. Because it's impossible to satisfy because I cannot guarantee that the subtraction between *ck* and *bn* is always greater than 0, *c* and *b* are constants. The latter is caused because the recurrence must be nonnegative. So my mistake is that I written a bad inductive hypothesis and if we consider the correct one it's unsatisfiable because bad subtraction was made. I think that everything is true.....

Comment: About the base case I think that it's not necessary because T(b), that's the base case, is constant. So you can always find a good constant for asymtotic inequality, if everything in the inductive step is **valid**. Furthermore on the book the base case isn't specified.

Comment: Every induction needs a base case. Without a base case you cannot conclude anything. It might be that the base case is trivial, but you still need it.

Comment: Yeah I know. What can I do when the base case isn't specified? I assume a constant value? Is the previous reasoning about my mistake valid?

Comment: You can assume a constant value for any particular value of $n$ you wish, since $T(n)$ is defined for all $n$ (i.e. the underlying algorithm always terminates).

Comment: Yeah. So, recapping there is essentialy one constrain: the lower-order term must be $o$. If not we cannot guarantee that the recurrence has a nonnegative value. Thank you for everything.